# No veo el menú en android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

**Buenas, quiero agregar un menú en la pantalla pero por algún motivo no lo estoy viendo.

Este es el xml `(res>menu>menu_izquierdo.xml)`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/cargarPrecio"
        android:title="Cargar precio" />
</menu>
```

Así lo creo en la actividad:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_izquierdo, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.cargarPrecio:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Hola", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Esta es el xml de la actividad donde quiero que se vea:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ListaDePrecios.Activity.ListaPreciosActivity"
    android:background="@color/blanco">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/logoapp"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">
            <TextView
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tvUsuarioBienvenida"
                android:textColor="@color/negro"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">
            <TextView
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:id="@+id/tvFechaActual"
                android:textColor="@color/negro"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TableLayout
                    android:stretchColumns="*"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="35dp">
                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/Cabecera"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:padding="5px"
                            android:text="Ciudad"
                            android:textColor="@color/negro"
                            android:textSize="26sp" />
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:padding="5px"
                            android:text="Mín"
                            android:textColor="@color/negro"
                            android:textSize="26sp" />
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:padding="5px"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="Máx"
                            android:textColor="@color/negro"
                            android:textSize="26sp" />
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:padding="5px"
                            android:text="Promedio"
                            android:textColor="@color/negro"
                            android:textSize="26sp" />
                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/RecyclerListaPrecios"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Y la actividad completa:

```
private RecyclerView recyclerListaPrecios;
private AdaptadorPreciosLista adaptadorPreciosLista;
private ArrayList<DatosLista> datosListaArrayList;
TextView usuario, fecha;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista_precios);
    recyclerListaPrecios = findViewById(R.id.RecyclerListaPrecios);
    usuario = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvUsuarioBienvenida);
    fecha = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvFechaActual);

    usuario.setText("Bienvenido quien quiera que seas.");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    String fechaACtual = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" + calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "/" + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) ;
    fecha.setText(fechaACtual);

    recyclerListaPrecios.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerListaPrecios.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    datosListaArrayList = new ArrayList<DatosLista>();
    String ciudad = "Córdoba";
    String min = "$15.80";
    String max = "$25.97";
    String prom = "$13.12";
    DatosLista dl = new DatosLista();
    dl.setCiudad(ciudad);
    dl.setPrecioMin(min);
    dl.setPrecioMax(max);
    dl.setPromedio(prom);
    datosListaArrayList.add(dl);

    adaptadorPreciosLista = new AdaptadorPreciosLista(datosListaArrayList, ListaPreciosActivity.this);
    recyclerListaPrecios.setAdapter(adaptadorPreciosLista);
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_izquierdo, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.cargarPrecio:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Hola", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Dejo la imagen del proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero, no se. ¿Alguien sabe por qué?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que el .xml el mètodo que lo infla es correcto , pero en este caso agrega la anotaciòn  `@Override` para que los mètodos sean llamados al iniciar tu Activity:

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_izquierdo, menu);
    return true;
}

 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.cargarPrecio:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Hola", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sigue sin aparecerme

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo el archivo menu_izquierdo.xml de tu pregunta es el correcto?

Comment: Si, he añadido la captura del proyecto